# Use sum and difference formulas to find the derivative of the function. How to make my answer match the correct answer?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of the function.

$y = 3x-1+\frac{1}{x}$

So I know we have to find the derivatives of the values with x. So for 3x, I did:

$\frac{d}{dx}[3x] = 3\frac{d}{dx}[x]$ where if $x^n$ where $n = 1$, then $\frac{d}{dx}[x] = 1$ so we have $ 3(1) = 3$

And so for the next value of x:

$\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{1}{x}] = \frac{d}{dx}[x^{-1}] = -x^{-2}$

So now I have this left over...

$3-1-x^{-2}$

$2-x^{-2}$

$2-\frac{1}{x^2}$

$\frac{2x^2}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}$ - Common Denominator

$\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2}$

but the book says the answer is: $\frac{3x^2-1}{x^2}$ **How did they keep a 3?**

Comment: The derivative of a constant with respect to $x$ is $0$.  You forgot to differentiate $-1$.  The derivative is $$3 - x^{-2}$$

Comment: Ohhhh... I assumed I ignored the -1 because in a previous example it did that, but now I just noticed it didn't ignore it, it was just 0. Thanks! It flew out of my mind because I learned that first and as I was going further and further into the book, I forgot about a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d \left( 3x-1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{dx}=\frac{d(3x)}{dx}-\frac{d(1)}{dx}+\frac{d(\frac{1}{x})}{dx}=3-0-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Comment: I'd never seen it be solved like this. Thanks! My book usually just gets rid of the d/dx like I did.

Comment: This is the way you are doing it, but written down explicitly and doing it in one go.

Answer (score 2):

Apply
$$\frac{d}{dx}[1]=0.$$
After six years at university those mistakes a somehow still common.:)

Comment: Good thing I asked because I would've been further confused down as I do my homework. I learned it first and as I learned more, I forgot a constant is equal to 0. Thanks! d/dx[n] = 0 where n is a constant.

Comment: Indeed. I'll perform the abstract calculations and then forget to carry the $2$.